# Play Video using Android Environment Directories as Path

Tags: android, video, directory, environment

i need to play a video in an application with Android, So i have a videoview C# code that finds the view from xml and sets a path to it and then starts...
The video `Ball.mp4` is in the Android default directory `Downloads` in my debugging device...
However i get the message, cant play this video everytime i launch the app...
I have used this to set the path `Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/Ball.mp4");` for the video but its not working...
here is more of the code that I used..

```
  VideoView videoView = this.FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);
//Code below seems to have a problem, please help
   videoView.SetVideoPath(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/Ball.mp4");
            videoView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            videoView.Start();
```

Am new to Android... If anyone can give me code that i can use to set the path with the environment logic, i will surely appreciate it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Downloads directory shows only downloads downloaded via DownloadManager, not all files in the directory.

your options

1. try getting the directory with direct reference.
   but from API 23 you have to give Runtime permissions in android
   and this method is not recommended because from android 9 android is restricted access to those folders.

   ```
      String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }



   public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
   ```

   }

use this to get permission it's simple don't forget to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
```

2. this option involves using MediaStore
   it's a little hard but you can get everything from these links

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video

Comment: i have the permission enabled in the ```manifest.xml``` file...

Comment: Yeah the file i copied to that directory though, it wasn't downloaded to that folder by default...I have another called ```Download```, Can renaming that to ```Downloads``` and then deleting this one help??

Comment: You should have runtime permission along with permission in manifest file..

Comment: Doing what you just Sayed will not let you learn anything... Even this method is will stop working from Android 11.so consider using second option.

Comment: Its not really trying to solve my problem i need path for video file without need to change my project code

Comment: it's not possible I guess